# How Do I Highlight a Cell a Certain Color if the values in two other cells match?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to get a cell to highlight with a certain color if the text of two other cells match. Has anyone else done this?

Example:

If the value in the cell A2 is "Car" and the value "Car" is in a range on another sheet, can the cell B2 be filled with a color?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *a range on another sheet* is ColumnC of Sheet2, then select B2, apply the Conditional Formatting custom formula:

```
=match(A2,indirect("Sheet2!C:C"),0)
```

and *certain colour* fill.

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved using conditional formatting.

Select the cell (B2 in your example) and in the menu bar go to Format > Conditional Formatting...

Here you want to use a custom formula. Specifically for your example, the formula to input would be:

```
=AND(A2="Car",COUNTIF(C2:C5,"Car")>0)
```

Note that the range that is being checked for "Car" is C2:C5, since you didn't specify any for your example.

EDIT:
Following the discussion in the comments:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet2!$C:$C,A2)>0
```

What this does, is that it looks for the value in A2 in column C in Sheet2 and if it occurs once or more, the cell that you have applied this conditional formatting to, will be coloured.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply. A better example of what I'm trying to achieve is:                  If the value in the cell A2 in Sheet 1 is "Car" and the value "Car" is in a range on Sheet 2, can the cell B2 in Sheet 1, be filled with a color?

Comment: So just to make sure I'm understanding you right. You want to check for the value in A2 in the range on Sheet2 or do you want it to be hard-coded to "Car"?

Comment: I want to check for the value in A2 in the range on Sheet2 .

Comment: Then it's actually even simpler :)

I've edited the answer to reflect this.

If this is still not what you need, would you mind sharing a dummy-sheet? Otherwise, can I kindly ask you mark the comment as the answer? :)

Comment: Thanks again but I went to add the formula and I received the following error: conditional format rule cannot reference a different sheet.

Comment: Sorry about that. It seems this is not supported. Try pnuts' solution below.